# What book (bible) does Kuma always hold?

Tags: one-piece

Bartholomew Kuma is always seen holding this book (a bible)

[image]

What is this book?

**EDIT**

What type of bible is this? Just a regular bible, a bible from the One Piece world, or what? Is he some kind of priest? His shirt has same pattern as the bible.

Comment: maybe some OPverse bible. or maybe it contains the details regarding lost century.

Comment: @Sp0T that's what I thought, but I never see any explanation on manga, but I never watch the anime nor movie so maybe there's some explanation about it

Comment: your edit made the question more interesting.. "A bible from the One Piece World.. " thats an interesting point.

Answer (score 4):

It's clear from the pic that it's The Bible. And I believe that there is only one Bible (content-wise). About different versions - they're all translated from the original Bible. You can get a clearer view about the different versions of Bible [here](http://www.bible.ca/b-many-versions.htm).

> [Kuma](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bartholomew_Kuma) is an enormous man, (22'6" feet tall). He is the tallest remaining Shichibukai (being one inch shorter than former member Gekko Moriah) and **is usually seen carrying a Bible.**

Source: [Bartholomew Kuma - The One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bartholomew_Kuma) (emphasis added)

Here's a pic depicting the name of the book much more clearly.

[image: Bartholomew Kuma holding a Bible]

Comment: FWIW there _isn't_ "only one Bible". The Tanakh, for instance, might be referred to as "Bible" in some settings---e.g. [here](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/vlavy/lavy_j.public.e_10.2008_gender_steriotypes.pdf), if you search for "bible" or similar terms---but it is _not_ equivalent to what Christians generally will mean by "Bible". (The book organisation is different, there's no New Testament, etc.) Granted, here, at least without more context, I would be willing to assume that this is just the Christian Bible.

Answer (score 1):

As the cover mentions, it is a [Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible)

> The Bible (from Koine Greek τὰ βιβλία, tà biblía, "the books") is a
>   canonical collection of texts considered sacred in Judaism and
>   Christianity. There is no single "Bible" and many Bibles with varying
>   contents exist.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible) The term Bible is shared between Judaism and
>   Christianity, although the contents of each of their collections of
>   canonical texts is not the same. Different religious groups include
>   different books within their Biblical canons, in different orders, and
>   sometimes divide or combine books, or incorporate additional material
>   into canonical books.

Comment: I know what Bible is, I mean what bible is it?

Comment: Did you mean "which version of the bible?"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Bible to Kuma is a religous text or historical account, the one he carries cannot rationally be any complete version of the Christian Bible that exists in our world without adding extreme plot elements that do not exist in universe yet or having the Bible be fiction in-universe.  These changes are not merely a sudo-Christian faith which we can infer already exists somewhere in universe and is not (alone) a major change.

Any version of the Bible makes reference to specific places and historical details (such as the Roman empire) that are undeniably real.  These places do not exist in the One Piece Universe.  I can only come up with the following ways to have his version be an exact duplicate of a real version: a sea identical to our world, accessible parrellel universes, the book from another planet, or OP world is a post apocalyptic version of our own.

Any of these would be large changes to the One Piece universe and, therefore, should be considered unlikely at this point in time.  The assumption should, therefore, be that Bartholomew Kuma's Bible is a version that does not exist in our universe.  The core concepts of the Bible do not need to be changed.